# Matplotlib Animated 3D Bar Chart with fixed Z-limits

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The following code works, except for one line; if I include `ax.set_zlim3d(minz, maxz)` (line 29) then the bars all become offset in the x-y plane. How can I alter this code to fix the limits of the z-axis without this happening?

```
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
# need to install ffmpeg, on osx; brew install ffmpeg
from matplotlib import cm, animation, rc
rc('animation', html='html5')
#from IPython.display import HTML
import itertools

def setup_plot(minz, maxz):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    xypos = [(3,3),(2,3),(1,3),(3,2),(2,2),(1,2),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)]
    xpos = [i for i,j in xypos]
    ypos = [j for i,j in xypos]
    zpos = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    dy = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    values = np.zeros(9)

    poly3d = ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, values, zsort='average')

    ax.view_init(elev=35,azim=45)
    ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)  # disable automatic rotation
    ax.set_zlabel('Potential (V)', rotation=90)
    ax.set_zlim3d(minz, maxz)

    showxy=False
    if showxy:
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
    else:
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    ax.grid(True)

    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
    sm.set_array([minz, maxz])
    fig.colorbar(sm, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

    fig.set_figwidth(8)
    fig.set_figheight(6)

    return fig, ax

minz, maxz = 0.5, 1.5
fig, ax = setup_plot(minz, maxz)

def update_bars(i, iter_vals, minz, maxz):
    xypos = [(3,3),(2,3),(1,3),(3,2),(2,2),(1,2),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)]
    xpos = [i for i,j in xypos]
    ypos = [j for i,j in xypos]
    zpos = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    dy = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)

    values = iter_vals.next()

    values_norm = values - minz
    colors = cm.jet(values_norm)

    ax.collections.pop()
    ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, values, color=colors, zsort='average')

    return

values = np.random.random((20,9))*1.5

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_bars, frames=values.shape[0], interval=600, blit=False, 
                               fargs=[itertools.cycle(values), minz, maxz], repeat=True)

anim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the limits on the z axis, you are shifting the plot and essentially zooming in on the bars, moving the center to (3.25,3.25) on the x-y plane. You can change the limits of the x-y plane manually by inserting the following lines in the `setup_plot` function:

```
ax.set_ylim3d(2,4.5)
ax.set_xlim3d(2,4.5)
```